# How to fix size for background image in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am using the gatsby -image-background slider and graphql for background image slider. But problem is, I want the background image to occupy only 25% of the whole space. If I reduce the height, the image is getting cropped which I don't want. And if I increase the height(or height and width both), then the background image takes 50% of the whole space.

Here is the code :

```
   query {

    allFile(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "background"},
    extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(png)|(jpeg)/"}}) {
totalCount
edges {
    node {
    base
    childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 600){
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp_tracedSVG
        }
    }
    }
}
 }
}
```

and in return

```
 return(
    <div style ={{backgroundSize:"auto 40%"}}>
      <Img
        fluid={images[index].node.childImageSharp.fluid}
        alt={images[index].node.base.split(".")[0]}
    />
    </div>

    )
     }
```

Please help.TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`gatsby-background-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-background-image/) as you said you have a wrong JSX structure. Your component should look like something like:

```
   <BackgroundImage
      Tag="section"
      className={className}
      fluid={imageData}
      backgroundColor={`#040e18`}>
      <h2>Your content if needed</h2>
    </BackgroundImage>
```

Your GraphQL query looks fine so you only need to pass the `fluid` data to `<BackgroundImage>` component.

Regarding the fit of the background image, you can play with it, using your previous structure as well as the one I provided, using `background-size` property, swapping between `cover` and `contain` should do the trick to fit the background image to its wrapper's size.